# Display text based on value with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to display an array and call a function to display variabled.

In my case the function returns 1, 2 or 3. Based on the  number i need to display the text say

if 1 then display result as begineer,
if 2 then display result as moderate,
if 3 then display result as expert.

I am aware of ng-show but is there a quick solution for this.

```
{{getdetails("skilllevel",course.courseID)}}`
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways you could do this in angularjs 1.1.5 and above:

`ngSwitch` is another option

```
<div ng-repeater="course in courses">
    <div ng-switch on = course.courseID">
        <p ng-switch-when = "1">beginner</p>
        <p ng-switch-when = "2">moderate</p>
        <p ng-switch-when = "3">expert</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another to use is `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-repeater="course in courses">
    <div ng-if = "course.courseID == 1">
        <p>beginner</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if = "course.courseID == 2">
        <p>moderate</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if = "course.courseID == 3">
        <p>expert</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you really don't want to use ng-shows and only have two option I would use a ternary if

```
<div ng-repeater="course in courses">
    <p>{{course.courseID == 1 ? 'beginner' : 'expert'}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I completed that job with other logics. I shall keep this logic to apply on other projects.